# 'games' or 'gaming' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Is there any reason to have both `gaming` and `games` tags?
IMO the `games` tag should be used instead of `gaming`. Should we replace all `gaming` tags with `games` or vice versa, or use tag synonyms instead?

Comment: have you created a merge request for this yet? If not could you?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi How do I do that?

Comment: (This sounds like another Meta Question!) http://askubuntu.com/tags/games/synonyms or http://askubuntu.com/tags/gaming/synonyms

Comment: @Marco tag this as `status-completed`?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely support `gaming` being merged into `games`.