# Can we merge/synonimize all the game related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Gaming.SE have an active monitoring of all the [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games) tags in all the SE network. They are several times more knowable in Minecraft servers installation and Game performance issues (since they get several times more question about these). Should we merge (and actively tag) game related stuff?

Related:

- ["Can I run X game that is Only-Windows game in Ubuntu?" we need a canonical question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7229/169736)
- ['games' or 'gaming' tag?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/732/169736)

Comment: And do [tag:game-recommendation] too please.

Comment: @Seth game recommendations are off-topic in Gaming... I really don't know why we accept those kind of questions altogether...

Comment: Well just kill that one then.

Answer (score 2):

You can do - as mentioned, we only actively monitor the [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games) tag, so any game related questions that pop up under a different tag will be missed by our community. The best way to handle this would be to synonimise all gaming related tags to [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games). From what I can see, this has already been done. (both [gaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gaming) and [game](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/game) are synonyms of [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games))

If there are any other additional tags that you would be considering creating synonyms to [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games) you should probably list them before a community consensus is built and any action is taken.

The exception is the [game-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) tag - any questions with this tag will be ignored by our community because recommendations are strictly off topic and are closed within minutes of being asked.

Comment: There's a typo: *both ... are synonyms of **`games`***.

Comment: @kalina Are you sure "recommendations are strictly off-topic"? I've not been very active on Ask Ubuntu recently, so it might be that I'm just behind on changes in policy. But I can't help but notice the significant number of [tag:software-recommendation] questions that remain open, including recent questions. Are game recommendations *specifically* what you're saying are off-topic? Clearly recommendations in the general sense of asking "What should I do?" are *not* categorically off-topic...

Comment: @EliahKagan I wasn't talking about recommendations on AU - I was talking about recommendations on Arqade - the purpose of this post is to increase visibility of gaming questions across the SE network, I was merely pointing out that recommendations shown to Arqade will get ignored due to being off topic on Arqade